# Filter list of dictionaries from a value and get items forward

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries, for example:

```py
list = [{a: "-1", month: 'January'}, {a: "0", month: 'February'}, {a: "1", month: 'March'},
        {a: "2", month: 'April'}]
```

So how would it be if I wanted to get the values of the list from an element that I choose. If I choose `a:0`, it should return all elements of this forward. It would be like this:

```py
[{a: "1", month: 'March'}, {a: "2", month: 'April'}]
```

if I choose:-1:
it should return this:

```py
[{a: "0", month: 'February'}, {a: "1", month: 'March'},{a: "2", month: 'April'}]
```

Also, how would it be if it is proposed that the same selection be included in the list?

Comment: …and please don't use ALL CAPS.

Comment: I'm guessing you know this already, but using `list` as a variable name is *bad* and your example data is not likely to be valid python.

Comment: Do you want to return all elements "greater" than `a:0` or all elements after the first element greater than `a:0`? Should we assume that by `a:0` you really mean `"a": 0` or are you really interested in comparing values by strings where "12 " is less than "5"? **Note:** people will help if you show an attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: @JonSG: "all elements of this forward" sounds clear enough to me.

Comment: @martineau Given the problems with the rest of the question even just the uncertainty of string vs numeric comparison, I think the poster should more clearly define what it is exactly they are looking to do. Is `a:10` "forward" of `{a: "2", month: 'April'}`. For that matter what is `a` here or `month`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to walk the list and return all the items after the dictionary containing a certain key/value:

```py
list_ = [{'a': '-1', 'month': 'January'},
         {'a': '0', 'month': 'February'},
         {'a': '1', 'month': 'March'},
         {'a': '2', 'month': 'April'}]

def forward(items,key,value):
    # Note: enumerate returns the index and value of each list item
    for i,d in enumerate(items):
        if d[key] == value:      # once the dictionary containing the key/value is found
            return list_[i+1:]   # return a slice of all items after that index
    return []

print(forward(list_,'a','-1'))
print(forward(list_,'a','0'))
print(forward(list_,'a','1'))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': '0', 'month': 'February'}, {'a': '1', 'month': 'March'}, {'a': '2', 'month': 'April'}]
[{'a': '1', 'month': 'March'}, {'a': '2', 'month': 'April'}]
[{'a': '2', 'month': 'April'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function which takes a tuple like `('a', '0')`. It will first get only dictionaries that have the first item in the tuple(assuming you have `{'b': "-3", 'month': 'April'}` dictionary) and sort it based on the second item in the tuple.

Then I will use `iter()` to get this sorted list's iterator to consume list items until I find the desired dictionary. Now it's time to call `list()` on it:

```py
lst = [{'b': "-2", 'month': 'April'}, {'a': "-1", 'month': 'January'},
       {'a': "1", 'month': 'March'}, {'a': "0", 'month': 'February'},
       {'a': "2", 'month': 'April'}, {'b': "-3", 'month': 'April'}]


def get_dicts(lst, key_value: tuple):
    k, v = key_value
    sorted_list_containing_k = sorted([d for d in lst if k in d],
                                      key=lambda x: int(x[k]))

    it = iter(sorted_list_containing_k)
    for dic in it:
        if dic[k] == v:
            break

    return list(it)


print(get_dicts(lst, ('a', '0')))
print(get_dicts(lst, ('a', '1')))
print(get_dicts(lst, ('b', '-3')))
```

output:

```
[{'a': '1', 'month': 'March'}, {'a': '2', 'month': 'April'}]
[{'a': '2', 'month': 'April'}]
[{'b': '-2', 'month': 'April'}]
```